# Function and strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, if-statement

I'm new to C and have started learning about strings. I want to create a function called

```
void SpaceRemover(char *input )
```

It should remove the spaced from a given string array that has lots of space

The code that I've produced so far removes all the spaces and doesn't provide the output I'm looking for. Can anyone help me with this?

```
char* SpaceRemover(char *input){
    char *output=input;
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i<strlen(input); i++,j++)
    {
        if (input[i]!=' ')   
            output[j]=input[i]; 
        else
            j--;   
     }
     return output;
}
```

I made this but I know its wrong and does not do what i want it to but honestly this is all i could this of -_-

Comment: If you showed us your code and the result you get with it, we could probably take a look and try to find out what's wrong with it.

Comment: Post the code you have! One solution could be a flag to indicate whether you just added a space (so that yo don't add two consecutive spaces). But without your code it's difficult to tell how such a flag method would fit in.

Comment: Ive posted what i got so far. Its terribly wrong and I'm getting frustrated because i cant figure our how to solve this problem and create a function

Comment: This shouldn't even compile, your function is declared to not return anything, but you are trying to return a `char*`

Comment: Your prototype has a different return type then your implementation. Please revise that.

Comment: The fun begins when you want to trim *leading* spaces, compress *included* spaces and remove *trailing* spaces as well. (e.g. `"   david    smith   "`)

Comment: Note: if the `*input` is pointing to a string in read only memory (or in flash) then it cannot be changed

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you remove all spaces.

```
char *SpaceRemover(char *name){
  char *output = name;
  int j = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++) {
    if (name[i] != ' ' || (name[i] == ' ' && name[i + 1] != ' ') {  
      output[j] = name[i];
      j += 1; 
    }
  }
  output[j] = '\0'
  return output;
  }
```

This condition should let one space through.
You might notice I replaced the `void` return type with a `char *` so t o use the function you will need to use:

```
name = SpaceRemover(name);
```

Comment: Hey I tried what you said but when I call my function with a given input i get something like this:
name = [ david smith (6 spaces then a smith)]....

Their is an extra smith at the end? Could you explain the reason behind this?

Comment: Doing `j--` inside `for` loop when it is modified by the `for` loop statements is a bad practice.

Comment: @Comte_Zero, In such case just add it as a "note" in your answer.

Comment: what should this `name != '  ' `do?

Comment: @Comte_Zero How are you going to handle if string includes more than 1 space in the beginning?

Comment: @Comte_Zero Are you removing it then?

Comment: @kiranBiradar No, should I ?

Comment: @Comte_Zero But You are code clearly removing all the spaces in the beginning and just keeping single space. Is it expected?

Comment: @kiranBiradar I would think this is valid, as it is not further specified by OP. I think it is a bit unclear that `output` and `name` are the same string. In this case I would just drop `output` completly. @Comte please check the last bracket it is not formated correctly.

Comment: My point is clear if you are going to remove spaces from the beginning then remove all don't just keep only one space.

Comment: @kiranBiradar It is, I'm not sure what the code is supposed to do in the end and this case was not specified, the question says to keep a space whenever there are multiple ones so I did that.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do as below

```
void SpaceRemover(char *name)
{
  int i=0,j=0;

  for (i = 0;i<strlen(name);i++)
   {
           if (name[i] != ' ' || (name[i] == ' ' && name[i+1] != ' ' && j!= 0))
           {
                   name[j++] = name[i];
           }
  }
  name[j]='\0'; //Terminate the string to avoid junk chars 
}
```

Where

```
if (name[i] != ' ' || (name[i] == ' ' && name[i+1] != ' ' && j != 0))
```

will let you  copy only if current char is not space or current char is space and next char is not space(to include single space apart in the beginning).

Also don't forget to terminate the `string`.

```
name[j]='\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be using a flag to activate when a space is met.

This might need to be tweaked if you want to remove leading and trailing spaces too.

A space will be added to output and the flag will be used to avoid the next ones to be added. The flag will be deactivated when something else than a space is met.

As stated Alex in comments, decrementing j in loop while it's incremented in the for statement isn't recommended.

I would copy each characters in the for loop instead of filtering a pre-copied output.

```
char space_found = 0;
char *output = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(name) + 1));
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(name); ++i)
{
    if (name[i] == ' ' and space_found == 0)
    {
        space_found = 1;
        output[j++] = name[i];
    }
    if (name[i] != ' ')
    {
        space_found = 0;
        output[j++] = name[i];
    }
}
output[j] = '\0';
```

Comment: The flag is a good idea but OP wanted to do the removal in place and the logic structure could also use some improvement/shortening.

Comment: OT: regarding: `char *output = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(name) + 1));`  1) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect and just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that expression.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score -1):

```
void spaceRemover(char* str)
{
    char temp[50] = {0};
    int j = 0; 
    strncpy(temp, str, strlen(str) + 1);
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if(temp[i] != ' ')
        {
            str[j] = temp[i];
            j++;
        }   
    }
    str[j] = 0;
}
```

if you have any questions, feel free to ask, Good Luck

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *rem(char *str)
{
   char *cur=str;
   char *nex=str;

   while(*nex)
   {
      if(*nex == ' ') nex++;
      else *cur++ = *nex++;
   }
   *cur=0;
   return str;
}

int main(void) {
    char z[]=" etc def etc    def ";
    printf("%s\n", rem(z));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Didn't the OPs question say to keep 1 space between words, but not at the beginning nor end?

Comment: @user3629249 where?